# Preprocessing steps to follow while cleaning and extracting text data from tweets

Tags: python, performance, strings, pandas, natural-language-processing

I have a dataset of around 200,000 tweets. I am running a classification task on them. Dataset has two columns - class label and the tweet text. In the preprocessing step I am passing the dataset through following cleaning step:

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd

def preprocess(raw_text):

    # keep only words
    letters_only_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", raw_text)

    # convert to lower case and split 
    words = letters_only_text.lower().split()

    # remove stopwords
    stopword_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if w not in stopword_set]

    # join the cleaned words in a list
    cleaned_word_list = " ".join(meaningful_words)

    return cleaned_word_list

def process_data(dataset):
    tweets_df = pd.read_csv(dataset,delimiter='|',header=None)

    num_tweets = tweets_df.shape[0]
    print("Total tweets: " + str(num_tweets))

    cleaned_tweets = []
    print("Beginning processing of tweets at: " + str(datetime.now()))

    for i in range(num_tweets):
        cleaned_tweet = preprocess(tweets_df.iloc[i][1])
        cleaned_tweets.append(cleaned_tweet)
        if(i % 10000 == 0):
            print(str(i) + " tweets processed")

    print("Finished processing of tweets at: " + str(datetime.now()))
    return cleaned_tweets

cleaned_data = process_data("tweets.csv)
```

And here is the relevant output:

```
Total tweets: 216041
Beginning processing of tweets at: 2017-05-16 13:45:47.183113
Finished processing of tweets at: 2017-05-16 13:47:01.436338
```

It's taking approx. 2 minutes to process the tweets. Although it looks relatively a small timeframe for current dataset I would like to improve it further especially when I use a dataset of much bigger size.

Can the steps/code in the `preprocess(raw_text)` method be improved in order to achieve faster execution?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see what the bottleneck is?

Comment: No. Never tried that. I am fairly new to python. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying my answer from SO:

You can use `pandas` [vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) to do your processing and it also removes the `for` loop for more efficient pandas operations, this should give you some speed.

```
# column you are working on
df_ = tweets_df[1]

stopword_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))

# convert to lower case and split 
df_ = df_.str.lower().split()

# remove stopwords
df_ = df_.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopword_set])

# keep only words
regex_pat = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df_ = df_.str.replace(regex_pat, '')

# join the cleaned words in a list
df_.str.join("")
```

Also I've changed your regex to `[^a-zA-Z\s]` so that it does not match the space character.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all those steps with a single list comprehension which will give you a bit more speed. This runs around 30-40% quicker:

```
def preprocess2(raw_text):
    stopword_set = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    return " ".join([i for i in re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', "", raw_text).lower().split() if i not in stopword_set])
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because low rep but I just wanted to add a quick note. It's the same comment i made on your post on StackOverflow before you moved your post.

If you use a Deque instead of a list for *cleaned_tweets*, and you insert in front of the list instead of appending, do you gain performance?

I believe it would speed this part `cleaned_tweets.append(cleaned_tweet)`.

Edit: For the preprocess, in fact I thought about something. Did you try passing the *stopwords* set as a parameter instead of creating it each time for every tweet? If the *stopwords* set is big, could help a bit. 
It also make your preprocess function a bit more generic.

Comment: Sure thing. But I am more interested in increasing the performance of what is happening inside the preprocess(raw_text) function.

Comment: Ok sorry then, I have nothing to add on the preprocess sadly, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I can speed it up.

First: 
Detailed measurements.  You have a time-measurement already.
You are doing 4 fairly heavy processing tasks (split, join, etc).  Measure each of these seperately.

Speedup:  Your stopwords is an unordered set. Python must search the entire set to know if a word matches.  Change this to a map - searching will be much faster.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `set` uses hash-based lookup, same as `dict`.

Comment: Argh. Facepalm. You are right!